# How long do ingame items last before they disappear

Tags: rust

There are boxes, wooden structures and metal structures.   How many days does it take for the to disappear.  There are also corpses that disappear after a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

You will find all the despawn duration on this wiki : http://playrustwiki.com/wiki/List_of_things_to_Craft. Click on any item in the list to see its duration.

House structure items, when placed, disappeared after that time if no campfire is lit once every day. For example, the wood wall will disappear after 5 days (see http://playrustwiki.com/wiki/Wood_Wall).

Some structures (like the spike walls, both regular and large) requires that you "heal" them by equipping wood in a quick slot item and, while looking at the spike wall, hit the shortcut key assigned to the quick slot it is in. You should get a message "xx healed yyyy/zzzz". xx is the amount of hit point healed by your wood, yyyy the current health of the spike wall and zzzz it's maximum. If the spike wall HP drops to 0, it will break and disappear.

Comment: I'm not seeing despawn data on that web page.

Comment: Well, as he did not ask for a specific item, I linked the page that links all the items... Feel free to click on any link, like http://playrustwiki.com/wiki/Camp_Fire and you will see (excerpt) "Campfires despawn after 2 hours if it has not been used even when there are items in the inventory of it."

Comment: some items are not listed, like wooden storage box. whats the default there?

Comment: You will notice that the original question was asked and answered more than a year ago. Since then, the game has evolved a lot, and the wiki does not always reflect the latest evolutions.